# SQL Server: Find out unused queries

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a database with hundreds of queries created by many people over the years. Now I can investigate for each query if any SSRS report, application for the database or other queries are using each query manually, but as everyone can imagine this is penal labor...

So I found some articles in the web about unused tables or procedures.
So as list all queries with

```
SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE type = 'V' AND is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Can I somehow find out if this query is ever been called in a period of time?

E.g. since start which I can get via

```
SELECT sqlserver_start_time  AS LastSQLServiceRestart FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

then I would take this date and list all views that aren't used in this time until now.

Comment: Have you reviewed this [earlier question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/146847) about objects' last usage time?

Comment: I just found this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39596/sql-server-how-to-detect-unused-views-and-or-get-usage-stats and try out this atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

In general, nothing exists built in that automagically keeps count like this. Some people tend to use indexes on a table as last access but that's sketchy at best.

The honestly best thing you can do is create an audit, trace, or extended event session and garner the object usage from that. This will also require extra work on things such as stored procedures where the procedure is executed and then may touch multiple or no tables, views, etc., based on logical flow.